# Which is the best book out there to learn Linq, including Linq to Entities?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, .net-3.5

I heard lots of reviews on the book Linq in Action, but it does not cover Linq to Entities. 
Please provide your feedback on the books you may have read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this, it may help till a good book appear: http://weblogs.asp.net/zeeshanhirani/archive/2008/12/05/my-christmas-present-to-the-entity-framework-community.aspx

Answer (score 6):

[LINQ in Action](http://www.manning.com/marguerie/) is a good book for understanding the principles of LINQ, and LINQ-to-SQL in particular.

[C# in Depth](http://manning.com/skeet/) is good for understand how LINQ works at the language level, including query syntax, extension methods and expression trees.

EF... trickier. One problem is that it is likely to change quite a bit between now and the next version due to the ["thunderdome" scenario](http://codebetter.com/blogs/ian_cooper/archive/2008/11/03/linq-to-sql-ef-and-the-thunderdome-solution.aspx).

Comment: Put simply: I'm reluctant to invest the time reading one if I know it is going to change significantly. And I don't want to recommend any I haven't read. I'm kinda waiting for vNext...

Answer (score 2):

The LINQ in Action book is pretty good. I've supplemented it with the Programming Entity Framework book (978-0596520281) which is pretty in-depth.

I found these books to be quite complementary. The LINQ in Action book gives you a good ground and, where you really need some meat (i.e. LINQ to Entities) the other text does the job.

Answer (score 1):

I have both but [APress's Pro Linq](http://www.apress.com/book/view/1590597893) is probably the one that I use most on a day to day basis. Unfortunately there's no coverage of Linq to Entities in the first (current?) edition.

Answer (score 1):

I've recently been reading an early draft of [Entity Framework in Action](http://www.manning.com/mostarda/); it seems to be along the right lines, but isn't complete yet.

At this point in time, I'd be wondering which books are covering the VS2010/.NET 4.0 version of Entity Framework, as there are considerable changes afoot. I don't know whether the above book will publish against 3.5 SP1 or 4.0, but it stands a better chance of being up to date than the existing dead trees.

Comment: I often do pay for Manning "MEAP" books; on this occasion I am reading it in a peer-review capacity, so no.