# Learning the Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I am interested in learning all about the Entity Framework.

I have found [these videos](http://blogs.msdn.com/adonet/archive/2008/05/20/how-do-i-new-entity-framework-videos.aspx).

I also have the book Programming Entity Framework, 1st Edition by Julia Lerman.

Does anyone have any other recommendations for learning this new technology?

Comment: Check out this post for some references: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/438742/which-is-the-best-book-out-there-to-learn-linq-including-linq-to-entities/636646#636646

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It will be good to follow some blogs like the [ADO.Net team blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/adonet/archive/tags/Entity+Framework/default.aspx) (tagged Entity Framework). It will give an idea of their design decisions, what it is lacking, future plans etc. There are some good articles in [MSDN Magazine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc501043.aspx) under Data Points.