# Resources for learning the ADO.NET Entity Framework CTP 2

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ado.net

So [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/adonet/archive/2009/11/04/ado-net-entity-framework-community-technology-preview-released.aspx) the ADO team announce CTP 2 of the Entity Framework.

What resources are about to help me learn this?

I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/643081/learning-the-entity-framework) which nicely describes earlier versions but it's the new version I'm specifically interested in.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eric Nelson in the UK DPE team has a nice and quite extensive list here:

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20210123025820/http://geekswithblogs.net/iupdateable/archive/2009/09/23/entity-framework-4.0-resources-ndash-documentation-links-best-blog-posts.aspx)

Marc

Comment: Phew! Lots there. Nice one, will review.